# Jsonp response get syntax error:invalid label with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to request jsonp data from cross server, request is successfully ok. But in console i got this error

```
(SyntaxError: invalid label
[Break On This Error]   
{"status":1,"movies":[{"id":1,"name":"Irma Crona","cinemas":[" )
```

Hope someone could help me to solve this problem, and i spend the whole morning to solve it.
Regards,

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type:"GET"
        , url:"http://mubi-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/home?callback=?"
        , dataType:"jsonp"
        , crossDomain: true
        ,jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
         , error: function(e) {
            debugger;
            console.log(e)
           alert(e + "Error");
           }

        });

        function localJsonpCallback(json) {
         if (!json.Error) {
            alert("error")
         }
        else {
            alert("success");
        }
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Here is jsonp response

```
{"status":1,"movies":[{"id":1,"name":"Irma Crona","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Dr. Jackson Lakin","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":3,"name":"Ms. Merlin Hodkiewicz","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":4,"name":"Chauncey Gerlach","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":5,"name":"Hal Larkin","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":6,"name":"Misty Blick Jr.","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":7,"name":"Eli Jacobi","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":8,"name":"Montana Hauck","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":9,"name":"Miss Velma Heathcote","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":10,"name":"Catharine Prosacco Sr.","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":11,"name":"Briana Luettgen","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":12,"name":"Dennis Wisozk","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":13,"name":"Tyrel Carroll PhD","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":14,"name":"Green Bauch","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":15,"name":"Marlee Jast","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":16,"name":"Mabel Wuckert","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":17,"name":"Katharina Bergstrom","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":18,"name":"Jayde Sporer","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":19,"name":"Merlin Jast","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":20,"name":"Elijah Kub","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":21,"name":"Clair Wuckert","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":22,"name":"Delta Vandervort","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":23,"name":"Miss Creola Harber","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":24,"name":"Kacie Wyman","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":25,"name":"Russel Harvey","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":26,"name":"Enid Leannon","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":27,"name":"Reva Hodkiewicz","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":28,"name":"Heaven Fritsch","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":29,"name":"Kaylah Gibson","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"id":30,"name":"Ms. Litzy Bergnaum","cinemas":[{"name":"Nay Pyi Daw Cinema"},{"name":"Shay Saung Cinema"}],"categories":[{"name":"Scifi"},{"name":"Horror"},{"name":"Action"}]}]}
```

Comment: can you show us your json response?

Comment: Hi Spokey, I added json response..

Answer (score 0):

Your API endpoint does not seem to support JSONP:

http://mubi-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/home?callback=something

The response should start with `something(...` in this case, so it should return JavaScript instead of pure JSON.

Comment: If so what i would have to do my server to support JSONP.

Comment: Your server has to wrap your JSON in a function call if the `callback` parameter is given.

Comment: Hi Sascha, why does server need to wrap my json in a function call when callback para is given? I am not clear, if u don't mind can u explain it to me? or suggest some link, it is helpful.